# Splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

For $p$ prime, how can we show that the splitting field of $f(x)=x^{p-1}-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ coincides with $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

The roots of $f(x)$ are the $p-1$ roots of unity. I think I am correct in saying that $\mathbb{Z}_p(\zeta)$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive root $(p-1)^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. I am not quite sure where to go from here however. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Hensel's lemma.

Comment: That’s assuming, @CJDowd , that by “$\Bbb Z_p$”, OP meant the $p$-adic integers. How about it, Maddiemoo?

Comment: Do you know a theorem that tells you the roots of unity modulo $p$? Perhaps they are already in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, in which case the splitting field is ...

Comment: @Lubin I do not know Hensel's lemma.

Comment: @EthanBolker I know that if $\zeta$ is a primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, then $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong U(n)$.

Comment: You are overthinking this. Fermat's (Little) Theorem tells you something important about what happens in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. You care about field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, not $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: By $\Bbb{Z}_{p}$ do you mean the p-adic integers or do you mean $\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}}$? i.e. the field $\mathbb{Z_{p}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by $\Bbb{Z}_{p}$ you mean the field $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ that is the field of integers modulo $p$. Then do as follows:-

for any non-zero $a\in\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ you have $a^{p-1}=1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

But this polynomial itself has degree $p-1$ and hence can have atmost $p-1$ roots.

So all the $p-1$ elements of $\Big(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}\Big)^{\times}$ are itself the roots of this polynomial.

And since $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ does not have any proper subfield of order $p-1$. , it follows that it is the splitting field.

More generally a field of order $p^{n}$(denoted by $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$) is precisely the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^{n}}-x$.

You can argue like above result to prove this. See that all elements of the field are roots of this polynomial and the smallest subfield containing $p^{n}$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ is $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ hence it is the splitting field.

Consequently you can use the uniqueness of splitting field to conclude that any finite field of order $p^{n}$ is precisely the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^{n}}-x\in \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}[x]$. (Note that any field of characteristic $p$ contains $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{pZ}}$ as it's prime subfield.

Also a slight piece of advice regarding notation. Most people use $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ to denote the field of integers modulo $p$ in order to avoid confusion with the p-adic integers.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful and useful to know!